# Set base path for follow-up HTTP request

Tags: http, go

Suppose there is a file called `foo.html` and a project structure that looks like this:

```
|--styles
|    |--style.css 
|--pages
|    |--foo.html
```

`foo.html` contains (among other stuff):

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
```

Now, when the client requests for `pages/foo.html`, it will see the link to the css file and it will make a follow-up request to `pages/styles/style.css`. Is there a way I can instead tell it from the file server to make a request to `styles/style.css` rather than `pages/styles/style.css`?
I'm using the Go `http` library from the standard library.

Comment: The `href` is using a relative path. Change the href to use an absolute path: `href="/styles/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are already using [http](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) go package. Here is the below sample code which can help you to achieve what you intend to do:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello1\n")
}

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./page/static"))
    http.Handle("/page/styles/", http.StripPrefix("/page/styles/", fs))

    page_fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./page"))
    http.Handle("/page/", http.StripPrefix("/page/", page_fs))

    http.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)
    log.Println("Listening on :3000...")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need explanation.